# Flink keyedStream count states

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have configured flink to read from a topic. These are some alarms coming from devices.

The genericEvent and DeviceState are simple POJO

```
class GenericEvent {
   String deviceName, region, alert;
   Long timestamp;
}
class DeviceState{
   String deviceName, status;
   Long timestamp;
}
```

EventEvaluator is a process function which determines the state of device (either UP or DOWN)

I have gone this far

```
DataStream<GenericEvent> genericStream = env.addSource(kafkaSource);
SingleOutputStreamOperator<DeviceState> deviceStateStream = genericStream.keyBy(GenericEvent::getDevice).flatMap(new EventEvaluator()); 
SingleOutputStreamOperator<DeviceState> downNodes = nodesStatuses.filter(nodeDownFilter);
```

...

```
private static FilterFunction<DeviceState> nodeDownFilter = new FilterFunction<DeviceState>() {
        @Override
        public boolean filter(DeviceState deviceState) {
            if (deviceState.getState().equals("DOWN"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Now I need to count the number of devices which are in state of DOWN.
How can that be done
After that, I need to count devices with down status in each region.(regions can be SOUTH/NORTH/EAST/WEST)
Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

We can use FlinkKafkaConsumer.assignTimestampsAndWatermark

Refer ***Kafka Consumers and Timestamp Extraction/Watermark Emission*** section

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/

```
    FlinkKafkaConsumer<GenericEvent> backupConsumer =
            new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>(CONSUMER_TOPIC, new DeserializationSchema(), properties);
    backupConsumer.setStartFromLatest();
    backupConsumer.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(
            WatermarkStrategy.forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5)));

 DataStream<GenericEvent> backupDataStream = env.addSource(backupConsumer);
    DataStream<DeviceState> result = backupDataStream.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<GenericEvent, DeviceState>() {
        @Override
        public void flatMap(GenericEvent value, Collector<DeviceState> out) {
            if (value != null) {
       //Add you logic here 
       out.collect(deviceState);
            }
        }
    });
    CassandraSink.addSink(result)
            .setHost(CASSANDRA_HOST,CASSANDRA_PORT)
            .setMapperOptions(() -> new Mapper.Option[]{Mapper.Option.saveNullFields(true)})
            .build();
```